# Render Error : Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

Tags: android

I used the lates version of Android Studio. It says that i have an error (Render Problem) in my App. I've tried to put

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

in styles.xml, but still won't work. Can someone give me a solution? I've just downloaded and started to study Android Studio yesterday, so i still don't know anything. Please Help me...

Comment: You need more info: what is your code, what have you tried, what is the other stackoverflow questions, what is the error, etc.

Comment: @geometrikal Sorry, i'm new to this thing. I've edited my question. Is my question already correct?

Comment: You can have a look at the help to see about asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help   There is a bit of a learning curve to using this site, but once you get over it, it is an awesome resource. One of the best things is to post a "Minimal Working Example" which causes the problem. Often in the process of doing this, you will find the error yourself.

Comment: I've never programmed for Android, but I'm going to guess it should be `coordinatorLayout` instead of `coordinatorLayoutStyle`

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem and i solved this way:

Go to: *build.grandle*(Module:app)

And change code with below:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yourname.yourappname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   // implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Sorry for my english